# "Unable to create project" error in Unity hub 3.1.2

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been having some issues with Unity so I installed the latest hub but now I can't create any new projects and I don't know what to do. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Here is what happens when I try to create a new project

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out the logs. In the main view of the Hub, on the top left there is a dropdown with a "Troubleshooting" option. In there you can open the log folder. Open the latest log file and see if it has any further information on why project creation fails.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means but the last error that shows up is this. 'ERROR.LAUNCH_EDITOR.ENOENT'

Comment: I'm not usually one to send you away from here, but you might want to ask this on the Unity Hub forum where the developers are active: https://forum.unity.com/forums/unity-hub.142/ One thing you could try (but it's a stab in the dark) is to return your license and then get it back again. Just to make sure it's not a credentials thing. That has happened to me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

This is a path issue. All paths should be selected correctly.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved my problem on Windows when I instal Unity on removable drive

Answer (score 2):

Here is my tried and tested method that works:

1. Install Unity and all the components Manually without using the Unity Hub
2. Allow Network Access and Administrator Permissions
3. Reboot your device after installation
4. Relaunch Unity Hub
5. Remove the existing license and add it again
6. Refresh License
7. Then go to create project
8. Make sure the installation directory is the same as the project directory. Outside of this, it might not work.
9. Give your project a name and select the template.
10. Click on Create Project and see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version on the top, this happened to me when I uninstalled the editor and installed a previous version. There's a drop down menu where you can select the correct editor version.

Answer (score 0):

In macos it is for permissions, I solved it by following these two tutorials

- Enable root user
  https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-root-user-mac/
- Execute Unity Hub as root user
  [https://es.wikihow.com/abrir-aplicaciones-con-privilegios-de-ra%C3%ADz-en-una-Mac#:~:text=Es%20posible%20abrir%20cualquier%20aplicaci%C3%B3n,a%20la%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20o%20computadora](https://es.wikihow.com/abrir-aplicaciones-con-privilegios-de-ra%C3%ADz-en-una-Mac#:%7E:text=Es%20posible%20abrir%20cualquier%20aplicaci%C3%B3n,a%20la%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20o%20computadora).

Answer (score -1):

When the editor is installed in a non-C drive, the editor has no right to create objects in any path

Unistall Unity Editor and install it in C:*

https://forum.unity.com/threads/if-unity-hub-didnt-be-installed-in-c-you-cannot-create-project.1375554/

report bug